# Use the percentage error in a figure title

Tags: python, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4gnl.png)

I need to include my percentage error in my figure title.

```
plt.title('Percentage error= %.3f' %(error))
```

This the code I'm using. This doesn't put a % sign after the error. How do I change this code so that it looks like the one in the picture. I've tried messing with it but I keep getting incomplete formats and errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.title('Percentage error= %.3f' %(error))
```

should become

```
plt.title('Percentage error= %.3f%%' %(error))
```